# Xcode does not find plist although there is one

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

As I wanted to run my App, Xcode suddenly can not find the Info.plist.
I´ve made another one and changed the Plist-location in the "Build Settings" area but does not work as well. 
Xcode says:

> /* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
>   : error: The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
>       Failure Reason: The file doesn’t exist.
>       Underlying Errors:
>           Description: The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory
>           Failure Reason: No such file or directory

Its the 5th beta of Xcode 7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your plist path is incorrect. It will to be that:

[image]

rather than:

[image]

For example: my project name is "TestCustomNSButton" so the path will be:

[image]

Hope this have helped you!

Comment: If I do this Xcode can´t find it as well but then  can choose a plist in my "General" options and if I choose the right plist there a two issues:       >Check dependencies
Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file '/Users/felixhess/Desktop/The real Social Center+/The real Social Center/Info.plist'.
and /Users/felixhess/Desktop/The real Social Center+/Info.plist:0: error: reading data: The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

Comment: Please check your plist file real path in `Finder`. I noticed that the error tips contains the `/Users/felixhess/Desktop/The real Social Center+/The real Social Center/Info.plist` and `/Users/felixhess/Desktop/The real Social Center+/Info.plist`. I think it's the point of the issue.

Comment: Xcode finds the the plist and can show the plist in the "Info" tab and I copied and pasted in both files. But the issue is there.

Comment: If possible, could you send me your project?

Comment: I´m sorry but I can´t do it. What files do you need?

Comment: Oh wait I can send you the whole issue message

Comment: It´s not the whole because it would be too long:(                                             /* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
: error: The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
    Failure Reason: The file doesn’t exist.
    Underlying Errors:
        Description: The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory
        Failure Reason: No such file or directory

Comment: Could you do that make the project copied and remove all files of `*.h` and `*.m` and send me the copied? I just need the project configuration file and the directory structure of the project.

Comment: everything is default apart from the plist location

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87093/discussion-between-bannings-and-developer-he).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

I choose the file Inspector of the storyboard and turned the Build for version to Development Target.

Storyboard -> File Inspector -> Builds For -> Project Development Target

I hope that solves your problems!